# If an application is vulnerable to stored XSS vulnerability but only an admin could put XSS payloads into the application. Is it a valid security bug?

Tags: javascript, security, web-applications, xss

A web application is vulnerable to stored XSS vulnerability but only the admin user has an access to the console and can insert data or XSS payload. And addition to this the application is NOT vulnerable to CSRF and access control attacks.

So is it a valid security bug? And Should I fix this one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My personal opinion: Yes.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is an valid security bug, although it reduces the risk factor because only an authorized user is able to put the xss payload. Many of the webapps ( like wp , etc ) allow privilaged account to put unfiltered html content , but if there are multiple admins then this could lead to a horizontal privilaged escalation or takeover if the xss could be exploited by one admin to takeover other admin .

Answer (score 0):

There is no definitive answer, it depends. You can choose to accept the associated risk or not.

Maybe admins can do whatever they want in your application, but consider auditing for example. What if one of them wants to conceal his actions and make it appear like another admin did something? XSS would be a good option for that.

Also there might be things not even admins can do in the application. For a very arbitrary example, consider an admin having a website where he wants to generate pageviews (or have others exploit stuff). Putting in an XSS to your application to generate a pageview on his website from the victim browser might be valuable in certain scenarios. In an example probably closer to real life, an admin might attack other admins' TLS sessions (for example to eavesdrop on their passwords, which is likely used elsewhere too). For certain TLS attacks, some level of control of the client (ie. XSS) is necessary. Or in very high privacy applications (ones used through onion networks, ie. the "dark net"), XSS may be used to reveal the real client IP address.

So in general, an XSS does not only affect the application itself. It affects the client that runs the payload, in ways sometimes quite unexpected. If there is only one admin, being able to perform XSS on himself only, well, you could argue that's not that much of a risk. But still, what if somebody else gains access to the database for example, and inserts an XSS payload for an admin to run? Sure, that may not be easily possible, but according to the defense in depth principle, fixing all known vulnerabilities is a good layer of protection against that too. This could also happen via an attacker having access to a logged on admin client (an admin leaving his PC unattended for a while).

Maybe these risks don't directly affect you, and these are only a few that came to mind right now. But in my opinion these all point to XSS be fixed, regardless of where, how, or by whom it may be exploitable.

Comment: Consider also an admin who is tricked into adding dangerous content via social engineering.

Answer (score 0):

For a more authoritative source, consider the CVSS (Common Vulnerability Scoring System). Without all of the details, it's hard for me to rate this vulnerability, but I imagine it would be something like this:

https://www.first.org/cvss/calculator/3.0#CVSS:3.0/AV:N/AC:L/PR:H/UI:N/S:C/C:N/I:L/A:N

It has a field for PR (privileges required), and it's set to high, meaning it requires administrator access. You can change it to none to see how this affects the overall score. You can mouse over each field to get an idea of what they mean, and maybe modify it accordingly (though, I would recommend a security focused person be the one to do this).

So, basically, it's definitely a valid security bug, but it looks like it has a score of 4.1 (medium severity).

You have a medium severity security bug, and it's up to you and your organization to address that risk. Perhaps given the existing mitigating circumstances, you will choose to accept the risk. Perhaps you'll just prioritize other things first, or maybe you'll add further mitigations such as 2FA or advanced monitoring to ensure that the admin account is less likely to be compromised.

As a security person, I would always recommend fixing this. Furthermore, XSS can be an indicator that there are other more serious vulnerabilities in the code as well. Perhaps a penetration test or security code review would be appropriate next steps.